# concatenar archivos .XLS

Tags: linux

tengo en una carpeta muchos xls, y los quiero concatenar todos de forma vertical, es decir, juntarlos en un mismo xls, pero solo consigo concatenar dos, no entiendo porqué. Estoy utilizando este comando:

cat Rot*.xls > consol_Rot.xls

De forma que me debería coger todos los ficheros que empiezan por Rot y con extensión xls, y concatenarlos en un fichero que se llame consol_Rot.xls, pero solo lo hace con los dos primeros.

Alguien me puede ayudar? Sabéis cómo puedo hacerlo? son más de doscientos. 
También necesitaría pasarlos a texto plano, pero esto creo que con línea de comandos no estoy seguro de que se pueda hacer.

Gracias!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Estás usando `>`, lo cual **sobreescribe** el contenido antiguo; es decir, cada **2** archivos, **elimina** el contenido antiguo de `consol_Rot.xls`.

Prueba

```
cat Rot*.xls >> consol_Rot.xls
```

fíjate que uso `>>` (**añadir**).

Ten presente que `>>` **siempre añade al contenido anterior**; si usas el mismo comando **mas de una vez**, el resultado será un archivo con los contenidos duplicados. Si vas ha hacerlo varias veces (por algún error o algo), borrar el archivo resultado (`consol_Rot.xls`) primero.